# How to upload data from a txt file to mongoose with insertMany method with mern stack?

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

I want to save multiple mcq question to mongoose. I have a `mcq.txt` file that contains 10 mcq questions. The code I have now gives me a status 201 response. But in mongoose, I can't find the data that just got sent.

I console logged the req.body for the backend code and it returns an empty object. When I work with a single file with the create method it works just fine. But with insertMany method, the response is ok but there should be 10 individual mcq question just as I have in my mcq.txt file. But there is only a single file with no data in it.

How can I upload the data from the file to mongoose with insertMany method?

**react AddMultipleMCQ.js file:**

```
export default function AddMultipleMCQ() {
  const [multipleMCQ, setMultipleMCQ] = useState([]);

  const buttonClickHandler = async () => {
    const postRequestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(multipleMCQ),
    };
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/add-multiple-mcq", postRequestOptions);
      const resData = await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setMultipleMCQ(e.target.files[0])} />
      <button onClick={() => buttonClickHandler()}>Add Multiple MCQs</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**backend for inserting multiple mcq:**

```
router.post("/add-multiple-mcq", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const multipleMCQ = await MCQ.insertMany(req.body)
    res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: multipleMCQ })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ success: false })
    console.log("server error: ", error)
  }
})
```

**mcq.txt file:**

```
[
  {
    "question": "question 1",
    "options": ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"],
    "answer": "option 2",
    "tags": "question 1"
  },
  .....
  .....
  {
    "question": "question 10",
    "options": ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"],
    "answer": "option 2",
    "tags": "question 10"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your data is looks like json file. have you tried to parse it as with ```JSON.parse```?

Comment: yes. is that wrong to do?